# 2 way binding issues with directives, controllers and services

Tags: angularjs

This is bugging me a bit.
I have a service that handles logo panels and a function that is used to navigate between the different panels.

When **getPanels** is invoked it sets the **currentPanel**, **index** and **length** on the service when all promises have completed (see **$q.all** in the **getPanels** method):

```
.service('ConfiguratorLogoService', ['$q', 'UploadService', 'LogoService', 'ArrayService', 'SvgService', function ($q, uploadService, logoService, arrayService, helper) {

    // Private function to build a file array
    var _buildFileArray = function (panels, files) {

        //--- Omitted for brevity ---//
    };

    // Create our service
    var service = {

        // Create our arrays
        panels: [],
        files: [],

        currentPanel: null,
        index: 0,
        length: 0,

        // Get our panels
        getPanels: function (container, garmentId) {

            // Create a deferred promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Create our arrays
            var panels = []
            files = [],
            promises = [];

            // If we have a container
            if (container) {

                // Get the containers children
                var children = container.children()

                // Loop through our panel's children
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

                    // Get the current child
                    var child = angular.element(children[i]),
                        childId = child.attr('id'),
                        childTitle = helper.extractText(childId, ':', 1);

                    // Create our item
                    var panel = {
                        id: childId,
                        title: childTitle
                    };

                    // Try to get our item
                    promises.push(logoService.get(garmentId, panel.id).then(function (response) {

                        // If we have any data
                        if (response) {

                            // Add the file to our array
                            files.push(response);
                        }
                    }));

                    // Add our child to the array
                    panels.push(panel);
                }
            }

            // After all the promises have been handled
            $q.all(promises).then(function () {

                // Get our files
                service.files = _buildFileArray(panels, files);
                service.panels = panels;
                service.currentPanel = panels[0];
                service.length = panels.length;

                // Resolve our promise
                deferred.resolve({
                    files: service.files,
                    panels: panels
                });
            });

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        // Get our next panel
        navigateNext: function () {

            // Create a deferred promise
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // Get the next index or reset if we reached the end of our list
            service.index = service.index === (service.length - 1) ? 0 : service.index += 1;

            // Set our active panel
            service.currentPanel = service.panels[service.index];

            console.log(service.index);

            // Resolve our promise
            deferred.resolve();

            // Return our promise
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        // Get our previous panel
        navigatePrevious: function () {

            // Get the previous index or set to the end of our list
            service.index = service.index === 0 ? service.length - 1 : service.index -= 1;

            // Set our active panel
            service.currentPanel = service.panels[service.index];
        },

        // Removes the file from azure
        remove: function (index) {


            //--- Omitted for brevity ---//

        }
    };

    // Return our service
    return service;
}])
```

which is fine, it works and the first panel is selected.
So, I have a controller, which is attached to a directive. The controller looks like this:

```
.controller('ConfiguratorLogosDirectiveController', ['ConfiguratorLogoService', 'RowService', function (service, rowService) {
    var self = this;

    // Set our current panel
    self.currentPanel = service.currentPanel;
    self.index = service.index;
    self.length = service.length;

    // Initialization
    self.init = function (container, garmentId) {

        // Get our panels
        return service.getPanels(container, garmentId).then(function (response) {

            self.panels = response.panels;
            self.files = response.files;

            // If we have any panels
            if (self.panels.length) {

                // Set our current panel
                self.currentPanel = service.currentPanel;
                self.index = service.index;
                self.length = service.length;
            }

            // Return our response
            return response;
        })
    };

    // Map our service functions
    self.upload = service.upload;
    self.next = service.navigateNext;
    self.previous = service.navigatePrevious;
    self.remove = service.remove;
}])
```

As you can see, when I get my panels, I set the **currentPanel**, **index** and **length** on the controller itself which I didn't think I would have to do because when the controller is invoked, it already has a reference to the service values. I figured 2 way binding would come into play and when the service values update, the controller would update too.

Anyway, I update the values after the **getPanels** method completes successfully. In my directive I have this:

```
// Invoke on controller load
controller.init(container, scope.garmentId).then(function (response) {

    // Map our properties
    scope.panels = controller.panels;
    scope.files = controller.files;
    scope.currentPanel = controller.currentPanel;
    scope.index = controller.index;
    scope.length = controller.length;
});
```

which again works fine. In my template I can see the first panel and it looks fine.
So, then came the next step which was my navigate functions. I started with **next** which I have modified for testing purposes so I can output the **controller.index** as well as the console.log in the service navigation function.
The directive function looks like this:

```
scope.next = function () {
    controller.next().then(function () {
        console.log(controller.index);
    });
};
```

When this method is invoked, I can see in my console that the service increases the index by 1 but the controller still shows 0 which means that 2 way binding is not working.
I am about to update my method in the controller to push the **currentPanel** and index to the controller, but before I do I thought I would ask here first.

So, does anyone know why my 2 way binding isn't working?

---

So my current workaround works, but I just don't like it.
In my directive I have done this:

```
scope.next = function () {
    controller.next().then(function () {

        console.log(controller.index);
        scope.currentPanel = controller.currentPanel;
        scope.index = controller.index;
        scope.length = controller.length;
    });
}
```

and in the directive controller I have done this:

```
self.next = function () {

    // Try to navigate forward
    return service.navigateNext().then(function () {

        // Set our current panel
        self.currentPanel = service.currentPanel;
        self.index = service.index;
        self.length = service.length;

        console.log(self.index);
    });
}
```

and in my service, it looks the same as before:

```
// Get our next panel
navigateNext: function () {

    // Create a deferred promise
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Get the next index or reset if we reached the end of our list
    service.index = service.index === (service.length - 1) ? 0 : service.index += 1;

    // Set our active panel
    service.currentPanel = service.panels[service.index];

    console.log(service.index);

    // Resolve our promise
    deferred.resolve();

    // Return our promise
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

This works, but surely this is not the way it should work.

Comment: I'm looking at your code and first thing that comes to my mind is that is very over-engineered, especially the use of promises, you create a deferred object and resolve it immediately

Comment: yeah that is just so I can see the index that is reported in the directive, if you look at **navigatePrevious** you can see how the method actually looked

Comment: If you could create a plunker demonstrating the issue it would be way easier to debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out [thanks to this article](http://juristr.com/blog/2014/11/learning-ng-databinding-doesnt-work/).

I just had to create an object in my directive and bind the values to that. 
Doing that fixed the issues.